# PHP Checkboxes won't undo disable attribute, but will uncheck

Tags: checkbox, javascript

I have a few pages of long code, but I'm having difficulty getting this to work. The following script checks all and and disables all checkboxes with a certain ID using an onclick command on one main checkbox. When the user unclicks that box, the checkmarks disappear, but remain disabled. Even if they hit the reset button, the disabled boxes stay.

Javascript:

```
 <script>
 function checkAllbase(bx) {
  var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    if(cbs[i].id == '1') {
      cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
      cbs[i].disabled=true;
    }
  }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: "*all checkboxes with a certain ID*" IDs should be unique to a single element throughout the entire document. They don't support reuse. A `class` name or [`data-id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*) may be a better fit.

Comment: i dont see you trying to remove the disable anywhere

Comment: Jonathan, I'm using 4 different ID's for 4 different groups of checkboxes because they're scattered throughout the file and there are at least 100 of them. 
Patrick, I don't know how with this function. They all uncheck and uncheck when I press the reset button, but the disabled attribute stays.

Comment: @user2590331, `.disabled=false` or `.removeAttr("disabled")`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Okay, and could I just put an else in that function with that in it? Or do you see a better option?

Comment: is this function supposed to toggle the check boxes on and off, and disabled and enabled?

Comment: @PatrickEvans That's exactly it. When the user selects a main package deal, it is supposed to check all boxes that go to that package and disable them as well. Then toggle off if that package is unchecked. Sorry, I've learned all of this in 2 weeks and it's a little sloppy.

Comment: @user2590331, see my answer for a toggle version of the function, it uses document.querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByTagName as its more flexible in getting the correct inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each checkbox input that is associated with a package a similar name or class. Without seeing your actual html, supplying sample html below

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="package1" name="package1[]" value="vacation">
<input type="checkbox" class="package1" name="package1[]" value="bonus">
<input type="checkbox" class="package1" name="package1[]" value="fries">
```

JS

```
function togglePackage(isChecked,packageName) {
  //Choose one of the two below to use

  //Below selects the inputs by the class name
  var cbs = document.querySelectorAll("input."+packageName);
  //Or Below selects the inputs by the input name
  var cbs = document.querySelectorAll("input[name^="+packageName+"]");

  for(var i=0; i<cbs.length; i++) {
        //Since they are either checked and disabled (both true)
        //or unchecked and enabled (both false) we can just use
        //isChecked to set both at once.
        cbs.checked = isChecked;
        cbs.disabled = isChecked;
  }
}

//Then somewhere call the togglePackage function
//bx here would be the main checkbox that you want to 
//have toggling the other boxes, and "package1" is obviously
//the name or the class you gave the checkboxes.
togglePackage(bx.checked,"package1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements remain `disabled` because the value being set is a constant (literal) `true`.

What you can do is copy `bx.disabled` throughout, as you're doing with `bx.checked`:

```
cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
cbs[i].disabled = bx.disabled;
```

Or add another argument to pass the desired `disabled` state:

```
function checkAllbase(bx, disabled) {
  disabled = disabled !== false; // limit to `true` or `false`, prefer `true`
  // ...
    cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
    cbs[i].disabled = disabled;
  // ...
}

// usage
checkAllbase(bx);        // disables elements
checkAllbase(bx, true);  // also disables elements
checkAllbase(bx, false); // enabled elements
```